# Apache Tiles: abstract definition extending another abstract one

Tags: jsp, tiles2, apache-tiles

I'm using Tiles 2.2 and I'd like to reuse a single JSP to display different messages. Messages have to be defined inside Tiles configuration file.

The following example is my approach: *base* is the base abstract definition all other definitions extend, while *display* would be an another abstract definition, used as a template for displaying messages. *page1* and *page2* are two final pages examples, each one displays a different message.

```
<definition name="base" template="layout.jspx"/>

<definition name="display" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="display.jspx"/>
</definition>

<definition name="page1" extends="display">
        <put-attribute name="message" value="This is one message!"/>
</definition>

<definition name="page2" extends="display">
        <put-attribute name="message" value="This is another message!"/>
</definition>
```

display.jspx would have something like this inside:

```
<tiles:useAttribute name="message"/>
Message: ${message}
```

But I couldn't make it to work, because when opening *page1* or *page2* I get an exception saying message attribute is null.

Is there an easy way to set up something like this, **without modifying base template and definition**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Tiles. I think I remember having to put type="string" on attributes of type string.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but I believe you need to add `cascade="true"` to your `put-attribute` elements for `name="message"`.